# dependsOn feature on build.gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 6.7.6 versionand i am implementing sonar branch analysis 
I tried using 
`build.dependsOn sonar` code in my build.gradle file to make sure the PR build fails when the sonar analysis fails

but somehow that line of code not seemed to be working

Is there anything wrong with the code ? or have an alternative way to fail the PR build on the feature level when the sonar analysis fails

Comment: Change it to `build.dependsOn sonar`, because you need to call the method `dependsOn` of the object `build` with the argument `sonar` in Groovy syntax. You can use parentheses, too: `build.dependsOn(sonar)`

Comment: sorry, i tried using build.dependsOn sonar and it wasnt working. dependsOn was working for other tests but only for sonar it isnt